# Pandas grouping based on a column in a very specific format

Tags: pandas

I have a data-frame df -

```
    a   b   c
0   1   5   0
1   1   6   1
2   1   7   0
3   3   8   0
```

need to group it based on column-c like -

```
    a       b       c
0   [1, 1]  [5, 6]  [0, 1]
1   1       7       0
2   3       8       0
```

It can be done through iterating over the df. Are there any other ways more like pandas grouping or something?

Comment: The output does not appear to match the input data. If you group by the `c` column, you will have only 2 lines... `c=0` and `c= 1` or I don't understand your logic.

Comment: @Corralien Let's assume that column-c is page no. So for a document, it could go from 0...n that's where the grouping should happen. i.e. for the above example - c: [0, 1], [0], [0]. Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems like you have to make group of first two rows. So make both the index same and apply groupby on index and get list of values for each group.. Check out my answer for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but do you need this?

```
k = 0
temp = []
for i in df.c:
    if i == 0:
        k+=1
    temp.append(k)
df = df.groupby(temp).agg(list)
```

**Output:**

```
        a       b       c
1  [1, 1]  [5, 6]  [0, 1]
2     [1]     [7]     [0]
3     [3]     [8]     [0]
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any loop. Here is the two line of solution.

- Change index 0 to 1 so that you can make groups on the basis of index.
- Make groups on the basis of index using `groupby` and get list of values of each column for each group

```
df.rename(index={0:1}, inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(list)

print(df)

          a       b       c
    1   [1, 1]  [5, 6]  [0, 1]
    2   [1]     [7]     [0]
    3   [3]     [8]     [0]
```